# How to safely read a file path from URL in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, security

I am in a basic Next.js/Node.js project, and want to load a YAML "page metadata" file to generate a social media image. The metadata only has title, url, and image and such. The problem is, I load this YAML metadata from a file that is based on the URL, which can potentially be hacked.

So if I have a URL like `/foo/bar/baz`, I want to load the YAML config for that page inside `$APP_FOLDER/data/pages/foo/bar/baz/metadata.yaml`. The problem I'm imagining (in Node.js), is you change the URL to `/../../something-secret` like even `/../../package.json`, and doing the following will load the package.json:

```
fs.readFileSync(`${process.cwd()}/data/pages/${urlPath}`)
```

So it would resolve to (for example):

```
fs.readFileSync(`./data/pages/../../package.json`)
```

I don't want that, that is a security problem.

So I think about the `path` module, and doing `path.relative(a, b)`, but I'm not sure that is correct or would solve the problem.

My question is kind of generic though, how do I (in Node.js) prevent a user from navigating the file system like this? How can I enforce "only allow searching within the `./data/pages` folder recursively"?

Comment: Can you use Nginx instead of Node.js?

Answer (score 0):

Could you put these static files inside the [/public](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving) directory of your Next.js project?  Then you could more safely fetch from URLs instead of local file system. Also, Since Next.js primarily makes isomorphic React apps, you will probably have trouble using `fs`, or other Node modules that you wouldn't find in the browser, unless you try the new experimental "app" directory.